# check if update is from oracle database user or from external application on database

Tags: oracle, triggers

Dears

I have an Oracle Trigger that Updates a Column named ChangeBY.

this trigger is fired when a user updates any record inside the database and places the username in the ChangeBY column.

The Updates are done from both sides, It can be an update directly from a database user or it can be from an external application connected to my database.

how can I check from where is the Update Coming? From database User or Application?

I want to put a condition inside the trigger to only run my code when any update on values is made ONLY FROM A DATABASE USER since connected applications changes the ChangeBY Column Automatically.

Is this Possible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I am litle bit confused about database user and application user. Since any application that might connect will internally use a database user only for update. You can check the current user who is logged in and trying to update
.
May be u can explain lil bit about ur application user.

Comment: Dear, application I'm using is maximo, when a user login to maximo any changes made inside the system, the changeby column will be updated by the maximo user logged In. what is actually happening is that after adding the trigger, any changes made from the system(Maximo), the changeby column is updated by users that are opening the database and not the maximo user. so because of this i want to add a condition to the trigger to check if the change are made from Maximo or from a user updating directly from database(Toad)

Comment: In this case you can do one thing check for the client from which the update is happening. I.e if the update is done from client like toad, sql developer u can easily track. V$SESSIONcan be used to track it. Hope this helps.

Comment: as far as the database is concerned there is no difference.  A user is a user is a user.  A connected session using some user account.  Even if a stored procedure, it is owned by some use account.  Beyond that, I think what you are looking for can be found by querying sys_context.  I leave it as an exercise for the student to look up the reference in the Oracle docs.

Comment: Yeaaaah totally agree.